# How do I connect to a local Microsoft Sql server 2012 Express database from a C# program?

Tags: stored-procedures, sqlcommand

Can someone please help me fix my connection string? I am an absolute beginner using the MS SQL Management Studio but I am an experienced C# programmer. I am trying to figure out how to connect to a local database on my PC. I just installed SQL server 2012 Express today and I created a table with one row of data. I am trying to access that table from a C# program. I've been looking for help calling a stored procedure (with no parameters) and it seems like I am doing everything right, but I get an exception error "Could not find stored procedure 'GetCustomers'."  I have also tried changing my the procedure name to "dbo.GetCustomers" and also "SqlTest.dbo.GetCustomers" and also "SqlTest.GetCustomers", but nothing seems to work. Clearly I am not connecting to my database correctly. I've been working on this for 4 hours now so it's time for me to stop and find help. I think all I need is a good connection string and the proper syntax for the procedure.

```
        Connect c = new Connect();
        if(c.MakeConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet data = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter();

                //changed to use stored procedure
                adaptor.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("GetCustomers", c.MyConnect);
                adaptor.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //adaptor.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();//this throws an exception.
                adaptor.Fill(data);//this throws an exception.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.WriteMessage(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                c.CloseConnection();
            }
```

My connection class contains the following:

```
string connection = Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectString;
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection);
sqlConnection.Open();
```

Connection string I have tried which seem to connect OK:

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
```

My Database name is SqlTest. I have tried several variations in my connection string, but most of them throw a logon failed exception error. I verified that my windows user ID has admin privileges for the database.

Connection strings I have tried which cive me logon errors:

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SqlTest;User ID=Raphael\couchpotato;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;        
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=dbo;User ID=Raphael\couchpotato;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=SqlTest;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=SqlTest;Integrated Security=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess all I needed was some sleep. ;-)

I needed to set all of my SQL server services to Automatic. For some reason, they were set to manual, and so they were not started.

Then, I also needed to set the correct server name in my connection string. This is the same server name that is used to logon when starting SQL Server Management Studio. Here is a connection string that connects and accesses the correct database and table:

```
Server=RAPHAEL\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SqlTest;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```